# $S[a,b]$ is dense in $PC[a,b]$ in the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove that $S[a,b]$ (the space of all step functions for all possible finite partitions with the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$-norm ) is dense in $PC[a,b]$ (the space of bounded piecewise continuous functions on $[a,b]$, which are continuous from the right, $\lim_{x\rightarrow y+0}f(x)=f(y)$, and for which $\lim_{x\rightarrow y-0}f(x)$ exists at each $y$ and is equal to $f(y)$ for all but finitely many $y$. the norm of $PC[a,b]$ is $\| f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|$).

I thought of writing it as the following:
we need to find a sequence $f_n \in S[a,b]$ s.t $\| f-f_n \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$, I thought of trying $f_n(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\chi_i(x)$, where $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n $ is partition of $[a,b]$, and $\chi_i$ is a characteristic function of the interval $[x_{i-1} , x_i)$, except for $\chi_n$ which is the characteristic function of $[x_{n-1} , x_n]$; but I am stumped as to how to show that $\| f_n -f\|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$?

Any tips or hints?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a quick proof (as opposed to one done "by hand"), then you could use the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: how would you prove it by hand?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: I would look for a proof of the above theorem and try to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: I hope you can help me this proof. on page 60 here:https://books.google.co.il/books?id=4ZZCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=knapp+basic+real+analysis&source=bl&ots=f6klyadQc1&sig=TlKjlpMq657VCf8i9hDDUIHLw3M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCWoVChMI2_3yi7-jxwIVSh8aCh3aGQFY#v=onepage&q=knapp%20basic%20real%20analysis&f=false there's the proof of Weistruass theorem, my question is how to change $\varphi_n(t)$, I thought of changing it to $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\chi_i(x)$, and the integral for $P_n(x)$ should be an integral from 0 to 1; if not then how to change this proof for this question at hand?